# Does Action<T> prevent enclosing class instance to be GCed when all other references to class instance are removed?

Tags: c#, reference, callback, garbage-collection

I wonder whether `Action<T>` prevents an enclosing class instance to be garbage collected when all other references to such class instance are removed during runtime?

```
public class Class1
{
    private Action<string> _callback;

    public Class1(Action<string> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string msg)
    {
        _callback(msg);
    }

}

public class Class2
{
    private List<Class1> _class1s;

    public Class2()
    {
        _class1s = new List<Class1>();
    }

    public void AddClass1Instance()
    {
        _class1s.Add(new Class1(OnClass1DoSomething));
    }

    public void RemoveLastClass1Instance()
    {
        if(_class1s.Count > 0)
        {
            _class1s.RemoveAt(_class1s.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    private void OnClass1DoSomething(string msg)
    {

    }

}
```

In this simplistic example, when I call `RemoveLastClass1Instance()` within `Class2` will the `Class1` instance be garbage collected or does it remain to hold reference to `OnClass1DoSomething()` via `Action<string>`? My goal is to completely remove `Class1` instances and have them garbage collected.

**EDIT: (further to Jon Skeet's comments, I added the following code to better understand**

```
public class Class1
{
    public event Action<string> Event;

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomething(string msg)
    {
        var handle = Event;
        if (handle != null)
        {
            handle(msg);
        }
    }

}

public class Class2
{
    private List<Class1> _class1s;

    public Class2()
    {
        _class1s = new List<Class1>();
    }

    public void AddClass1Instance()
    {
        var newClass1Instance = new Class1();
        newClass1Instance.Event += OnClass1DoSomething;
        _class1s.Add(newClass1Instance);
    }

    public void RemoveLastClass1Instance()
    {
        if(_class1s.Count > 0)
        {
            _class1s.RemoveAt(_class1s.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    private void OnClass1DoSomething(string msg)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Creating an `Action<string>` for `OnClass1DoSomething` will create a delegate maintaining a reference to the instance of `Class2`, not `Class1`...

Comment: Sure, the Class1 object will keep having a reference on Class2.  But the GC doesn't care about that, it looks for references to the Class1 object.  Since you removed the one-and-only reference stored in the List, there is none remaining and it will be collected.  Similarly, there has to be a reference to the Class2 object.  If there is none (the reference held by a Class1 object isn't enough) then both the Class2 and *all* Class1 objects will be collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder whether `Action<T>` prevents an enclosing class instance to be garbage collected when all other references to such class instance are removed during runtime?

No. If the delegate instance were still referenced elsewhere, and it had a target of the `Class1` instance, *then* it would prevent the instance of `Class1` from being garbage collected - but as it is, the target of the `Action<string>` is an instance of `Class2`.

Basically, there's nothing magical about delegates when it comes to garbage collection. If the delegate refers to an instance method, the target of that instance is held as a reference... so if the delegate is still reachable, the target of the delegate is still reachable. In your case, the delegate itself isn't reachable, and you're apparently not worried about whether or not the `Class2` instance can be garbage collected.

The change to use an event doesn't affect this at all - it's still the instance of `Class1` having a reference (via the delegate) to the original instance of `Class2`... the *only* reference to the `Class1` instance from `Class2` is via the list.

Comment: thank you, then why is it that I would have to first unsubscribe from events so that the enclosing class instance can be GCed? For example, if I exposed a public event as part of `Class1` and subscribed to it within `Class2` my understanding is that I would have to first unsubscribe before a `Class1` instance can be GCed, correct?

Comment: @MattWolf: No, the other way round - you'd have to unsubscribe from the event before the `Class2` instance could be garbage collected, because Class1 would have a reference to a delegate which in turn had a reference to the instance of Class2.

Comment: I get that, but I am at this point not concerned about `Class2` instances, only about removing and having `Class1` instances garbage collected.

Comment: @MattWolf: I'm not sure you do "get that" - my comment directly contradicts your previous comment. Do you now understand that your expressed understanding of events (that Class2 would keep Class1 alive, where Class1 is the event publisher) is incorrect?

Comment: I added another code snippet, so when I remove a `Class1` instance within `RemoveLastClass1Instance()` the instance will eventually be garbage collected regardless of whether I unsubscribed from the event within `Class1`? By the way my last comment was not a reflection of my misunderstanding your comment, I said I got it regarding the delegate but always thought the situation with an event would be different...

Comment: @MattWolf: An event is very similar to exposing a delegate field, other than encapsulation (you can't raise the event externally, or set it to arbitrary delegates - you can only subscribe or unsubscribe). Your example with the event works just the same way - once the last reference to a `Class1` instance is no longer reachable (e.g. after `RemoveLastClass1Instance`) that instance can be garbage collected regardless of *it* having a reference to the `Class2` instance.